# Knockout.js Dynamic loading of templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm building a helper function using `knockout.js` to dynamically create forms for a large application. So far I have been quite successful however I can't wrap my head around one thing.

I load in many templates and create components out of them all ending with one main component like so.

```
<my-component></my-component>
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
<textbox-component></textbox-component>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="textbox-template">
<input data-bind="value: myTextBox">
</script>
```

The problem that I face is that a template could also contain a template or component.

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
     <textbox-component></textbox-component>
 </script>
```

How do I dynamically load the template for that component onto the page in order to apply its bindings?

Comment: How are you loading them in now? Is it possible you can just include the dependencies with the 'base' template?

Comment: Currently I am loading it in by specifying just the template name ins an object which i use to get the file and append its contents to the page. I thought about adding in the dependencies but as our templates could get quite big it could be rather difficult. I thought of denoting all of my components with <component-{component name}> and then scanning the html for these templates but i feel that something could go wrong like that. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: I was kinda hoping to find out what type of server/backend you're using. There are a few of them out there and each have different ways. Also take a look at the word dependency, if your project **depends** on it. Why is it bad to include it? Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. All my templates are being loaded in via ajax gets and then appended to the page. I think that it is worth saying that every template is loaded in its own file. So if my template contains another template/component within it i would also need to get that file with that template to register my components and such.  All i do is recursivly loop over items in an object and build up components by loading multiple templates. And because one template could be used in multiple places i dont want to have to specify dependencies over and over.